# Cant find build.sbt for a play framework project

Tags: java, playframework, build, sbt, virtual-machine

My company has a virtual machine running a web app that uses play framework. I accessed the machine via WinSCP to retrieve the build.sbt file that is needed in order to run the play framework project. I found the folder containing the code, but it does not contain any build.sbt file. Here is the
[screenshot of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE4di.jpg).

How can the app run on the machine without this file? Am I searching in the wrong place?

Comment: Check what is inside the readme txt file. Maybe it helps :)

Comment: I did, it contains no useful info...